# R - Conditionally format cells by group in output xlsx

Tags: r, openxlsx

Is there a way to highlight cells by group that meet a specific criteria and write that conditional formatting to a .xlsx file? For example, I have the dataset below where Q50 is calculated as the median of the different "label" values (excluding Q50) within each unique "BIR_ID" group where each value is first determined within that group to be outlier or not, and if not then it is part of the median calculation.

```
median(x[which((abs(x-median(x)) /mad(x)) <2)])

BIR_ID  label        Jan        Feb
12001     SS   0.440000   1.320000
12001    nhd   0.000000   5.000000
12001    vic   6.202288   7.866950
12001    wab   1.770000   3.370000
12001    Q50   0.440000   4.185000

12002     SS  29.000000  71.200000
12002    nhd   3.000000  29.000000
12002    vic 138.290818 158.678870
12002    Q50  16.000000  71.200000
```

Is there a way to color fill the cells where the opposite of the condition is met within each group (i.e. it is an outlier within the group) or:

```
which((abs(x-median(x)) /mad(x)) >2)
```

The resulting dataframe would have the cells highlighted where those values were determined to be an outlier within the group:

```
BIR_ID  label        Jan        Feb
12001     SS   0.440000   1.320000
12001    nhd   0.000000   5.000000
12001    vic   *6.202288*   7.866950
12001    wab   1.770000   3.370000
12001    Q50   0.440000   4.185000

12002     SS  29.000000  71.200000
12002    nhd   3.000000  29.000000
12002    vic  *138.290818* *158.678870*
12002    Q50  16.000000  71.200000
```

Comment: R doesn't have formatting within cells of a frame, you'll need to determine the cells that need special formatting, then after you've written the table to a worksheet, use [`addStyle`](https://ycphs.github.io/openxlsx/reference/addStyle.html) (or similar) to change how the cell looks (in excel/calc, not in R).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like that, but either I didn't properly understand what conditions to apply to identify the outliers or OP incorrectly selected 158.67 as an outlier.

```r
dat <- read.table(text = "
BIR_ID  label        Jan        Feb
12001     SS   0.440000   1.320000
12001    nhd   0.000000   5.000000
12001    vic   6.202288   7.866950
12001    wab   1.770000   3.370000
12001    Q50   0.440000   4.185000
12002     SS  29.000000  71.200000
12002    nhd   3.000000  29.000000
12002    vic 138.290818 158.678870
12002    Q50  16.000000  71.200000
", header = TRUE)

out <- dat

mon <- c("Jan", "Feb")
out[mon] <- 0
for (i in unique(out$BIR_ID)) {
  tmp <- dat[dat$BIR_ID == i & dat$label != "Q50", mon]
  outlier <- apply(tmp, 2, function(x) (abs(x-median(x)) / mad(x)) > 2)
  out[dat$BIR_ID == i & dat$label != "Q50", mon] <- outlier
}


library(openxlsx2)

wb <- wb_workbook()$
  add_worksheet("dat")$add_data(x = dat)$
  add_worksheet("out")$add_data(x = out)$
  add_conditional_formatting(
    "dat",
    dims = wb_dims(x = dat),
    rule = "AND(out!A1=1)"
  )

if (interactive()) wb$open()
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, been busy with fieldwork these last couple of months! Thank you very much for the help Jan and R2evans, this is what I was looking for. I wasn't understanding the process of how to indicate which cells needed changed initially but this makes complete sense now. Thanks!